# Unwrap value from IO operation at a later time

Tags: haskell, io-monad

Hello i was wondering how can you unwrap a value at a later time in the IO monad?
If `a<-expression` binds the result to `a` then can't i use `(<-expression)` as a parameter for a given method eg:
`method (<-expression)` where method `method` accepts the result of the evaluation?

**Code**

```
let inh=openFile "myfile" WriteMode
let outh=openFile "out.txt" WriteMode 
hPutStrLn (<-outh) ((<-inh)>>=getLine)
```

I have not entered the `Monad` chapter just basic `<-` and `do` blocks but i suppose it has to do with monads.
Then if i want to pass the `result` if the evaluation to `hGetLine` can't i use something like:

```
(<-expression)=>>hGetLine
```

Comment: `<-` is not a function, it is part of the syntax. It is syntactic sugar for calls to `(>>=)`. This is why you can't use it in that way. If you do not yet want to use these `Monad` methods directly, how about `inh <- openFile ...; outh <- openFile ...; r <- hGetLine inh; hPutStrLn outh r` instead of the `let`s?

Comment: Ok `variable<-expression` cannot be used without the left argument.So i must enter the `monad` chapter.So i can use it like this? `hPutStrLn (=<<inh) ((=<<outh)>>=hGetLine`.

Comment: yes, it is part of the "`do`-notation". start with the do notation.

Comment: Was proposal [InlineDoBind](https://gist.github.com/evincarofautumn/9cb3fb0197d2cfc1bc6fe88f7827216a) which similar to what you are thinking.

Comment: `<-` and `do`, by definition, relate to monads (ignoring the `ApplicativeDo` extension). I gently suggest reading your chapter on monads.

Comment: @freestyle: Which I actually submitted as [InlineBindings](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/64) but my work on it fizzled out; I hope to get to it at some point still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already understand that `<-` operator kind of unwraps `IO` value, but it's actually the syntax of `do` notation and can be expressed like this (actually I'm not sure, which results you're trying to achieve, but the following example just reads the content from one file and puts the content to another file):

```
import System.IO

main = do
  inh <- openFile "myfile" ReadMode
  outh <- openFile "out.txt" WriteMode
  inContent <- hGetLine inh
  hPutStrLn outh inContent
  hClose outh
```

According to [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/System-IO.html) `hGetLine`, `hPutStrlLn` and `hClose` accept values of `Handle` type as an argument, but `openFile` returns `IO Handle`, so we need to unwrap it using `<-` operator

But if you want to use `>>=` function instead, then this is one of the options of doing it:

```
import System.IO

writeContentOfMyFile :: Handle -> IO ()
writeContentOfMyFile handler =
  openFile "myfile" ReadMode >>= hGetLine >>= hPutStrLn handler

main =
  withFile "out.txt" WriteMode writeContentOfMyFile
```

Comment: But what i do not understand is when do you use `=<<` and when `>>=`

Comment: it mostly the same, the only difference is the order of the arguments. For example, you have `line` of type `IO String` and want to print it. You can do it either by `print =<< a` or by `a >>= print`