# How to use an accumulator in a recursive IO action

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I have the following problem:

I want to read from a file line by line and write the lines to another file. However, I want to return the number of lines.

Therefore, inside a pure function I would use an accumulator like this:

```
function parameters=method 0 ......
                    method accu  {end case scenario} =accu
                    method accu  {not end case} = accu+1 //and other stuff
```

How can I achieve the same in a do-block without using another function?

**Concrete example**

```
module Main where 

    import System.IO
    import Data.Char(toUpper)


    main::IO()
    main=do
        let inHandle=openFile "in.txt" ReadMode
        let outHandle=openFile "out.txt" WriteMode
        inHandle>>= \a ->outHandle>>= \b ->loop a b 0>>=print . show 


    loop::Handle->Handle->Int->IO Int
    loop inh outh cnt=hIsEOF inh>>= \l ->if l then return elem
                                        else
                                            do
                                                hGetLine inh>>=hPutStrLn outh
                                                loop inh outh (cnt+1)
```

**Edit**

Refactored the way `loop` gets its parameters

**P.S 2** (after **K. A. Buhr's** thorough response)

**I.** What I really wanted to achieve, was the last expression of the `main` method. I wanted to take the multiple `IO Action`s and bind their results to a method. Specifically:

```
inHandle>>= \a ->outHandle>>= \b ->loop a b 0>>=print . show
```

What I do not understand in this case is:

If `inHandle>>=` is supplied to `\a ->` and then the result is passed to `...>>=\b`, do the variables inside the outer scope get closured in `\b`?

If not, shouldn't it be `>>=\a->..>>= \a b`? Shouldn't the inner scope hold a parameter corresponding to the result of the outer scope?

**Eliminating the do inside the helper method**

What I wanted to know, is if there is a way to glue together multiple actions without them being in a `do` block.

In my case:

```
loop::Handle->Handle->Int->IO Int
        loop inh outh cnt=hIsEOF inh>>= \l ->if l then return elem
                                            else
                                                do
                                                    hGetLine inh>>=hPutStrLn outh
                                                    loop inh outh (cnt+1)
```

Can't I say something like:

`if ... then ...` 
 `else`
`hPutStrLn=<<action1 [something] v2=<<action2 [something]  loop inh outh (cnt+1)`

where `something` could be an operator? I do not know, that is why I am asking.

Comment: Why do you not want to use another function? That would be the 'normal' way to do something like this in Haskell.

Comment: You are making the same mistake with `let inHandle = (=<<ioIn)` that was pointed out in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51491915/1126841). Please fix your code here using the [answer you accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51493281/1126841) before trying to ask further questions about this.

Comment: Use `loop :: Handle -> Handle -> Int -> IO Int` as the type instead, and pass 0 as the initial integer accumulator. In the recursive call, you can use `loop ioIn ioOut (accu+1)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out i didn't know if i have to declare the variable with `let` or i can just name the binding on the go `x>>=y` ,y existing from that point on.

Comment: You cannot create a new binding with `>>=`. `>>=` is just a function (so its arguments must already exist). In a `do` block, you can only create a new binding with `let` or `<-`

Comment: `inHandle>>= \a ->outHandle>>= \b ->loop a b 0>>=print . show` is really `inHandle >>= (\a -> outHandle >>= (\b ->loop a b 0 >>= (print . show)))` so when we get to the `(print . show)` both `b` and `a` are *in scope* -- the second  ( `\b -> ...`) lambda is *nested* inside the first ( `\a -> ...` ) lambda.

Comment: (contd.) and `hGetLine inHandle >>= hPutStrLn outHandle >> loop inHandle outHandle (cnt + 1)` is really `((hGetLine inHandle) >>= (hPutStrLn outHandle)) >> (loop inHandle outHandle (cnt + 1))` which is the same as `((hGetLine inHandle) >>= (\s -> hPutStrLn outHandle s)) >>= (\x -> loop inHandle outHandle (cnt + 1))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the answer to your last question still left you confused.

**tl;dr:**  stop using `>>=` and `=<<` until you master the do-block notation which you can do by Googling "understanding haskell io" and working through lots of examples from tutorials.

Long answer...

First, I would suggest avoiding the `>>=` and `=<<` operators for now.  Even though they are sometimes named "bind", they don't bind variables or bind parameters to methods or anything else like that, and they seem to be tripping you up.  You may also find the [section about IO from "A Gentle Introduction to Haskell"](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/io.html) helpful as a quick introduction to how IO works.

Here's a very short explanation of IO that may help you, and it'll provide a basis for answering your question.  Google for "understanding haskell io" to get a more in-depth explanation:

#### Super short IO explanation in three paragraphs:

(1) In Haskell, any value of type `IO a` is an IO **action**.  An IO action is like a recipe that can be used (by **executing** the action) to perform some actual input/output and then produce a value of type `a`.  So, a value of type `IO String` is an action that, if executed, will perform some input/output and produce a value of type `String`, while an `IO ()` is an action that, if executed, will perform some input/output and produce a value of type `()`.  In the latter case, because values of type `()` are useless, actions of type `IO ()` are normally executed for their I/O side effects, such as printing a line of output.

(2) The only way to execute an IO action in a Haskell program is to give it the special name `main`.  (The interactive interpreter GHCi provides more ways to execute IO actions, but let's ignore that.)

(3) IO actions can be combined using do-notation into a larger IO action.  A `do` block consists of lines of the following form:

```
act             -- action to be executed, with the result
                -- thrown away (unless it's the last line)

x <- act        -- action to be executed, with the result
                -- named @x@ for later lines

let y = expr    -- add a name @y@ for the value of @expr@
                -- for later lines, but this has nothing to
                -- do with executing actions
```

In the above templates, `act` can be any expression that evaluates to an IO action (i.e., a value of type `IO a` for some `a`).  It's important to understand that the do-block does not itself execute any IO actions.  Instead, it builds a new IO action that -- when executed -- will execute the given set of IO actions in the order they appear in the do-block, either throwing away or naming the values produced by executing these actions.  The value produced by executing the whole do-block will be the value produced by the last line of the do-block (which has to be a line of the first form above).

#### A simple exmple

Therefore, if a Haskell program includes:

```
myAction :: IO ()
myAction = do
  putStrLn "Your name?"
  x <- getLine
  let stars = "***"
  putStrLn (stars ++ x ++ stars)
```

then this defines a value `myAction` of type `IO ()`, an IO action.  By itself, it does nothing, but if it is ever executed, then it will execute each of the IO actions (values of type `IO a` for various types `a`) in the do-block in the order they appear.  The value produced by executing `myAction` will be the value produced by the last line (in this case, the value `()` of type `()`).

#### Applied to the problem of copying lines

Armed with this explanation, let's tackle your question.  First, how do we write a Haskell program to copy lines from one file to another using a loop, ignoring the problem of counting lines?  Here's one way that's fairly similar to your code example:

```
import System.IO

myAction :: IO ()
myAction = do
  inHandle <- openFile "in.txt" ReadMode
  outHandle <- openFile "out.txt" WriteMode
  loop inHandle outHandle
  hClose outHandle
  hClose inHandle
```

Here, if we check the type of one of these `openFile` calls in GHCi:

```
> :t openFile "in.txt" ReadMode
openFile "in.txt" ReadMode :: IO Handle
>
```

we see that it has type `IO Handle`.  That is, this is an IO **action** that, when executed, performs some actual I/O (namely an operating system call to open a file) and then produces a value of type `Handle`, which is the Haskell value representing the open file handle.  In your original version, when you wrote:

```
let inHandle = openFile "in.txt" ReadMode
```

all this did was assign a name `inHandle` to an IO action -- it didn't actually execute the IO action and so didn't actually open the file.  In particular, the value of `inHandle` of type `IO Handle` was not *itself* a file handle, just an IO action (or "recipe") for producing a file handle.

In the version of `myAction` above, we've used the notation:

```
inHandle <- openFile "in.txt" ReadMode
```

to indicate that, if and when the IO action named by `myAction` is ever executed, it will start by executing the IO action `openFile "in.txt" ReadMode"` (that is, the value of that expression which has type `IO Handle`), and that execution will produce a `Handle` which will be named `inHandle`.  Ditto for the next line to produce and name an open `outHandle`.  We will then pass these open handles to `loop` in the expression `loop inHandle outHandle`.

Now, `loop` can be defined like so:

```
loop :: Handle -> Handle -> IO ()
loop inHandle outHandle = do
  end <- hIsEOF inHandle
  if end
    then return ()
    else do
      line <- hGetLine inHandle
      hPutStrLn outHandle line
      loop inHandle outHandle
```

It's worth taking a moment to explain this.  `loop` is a fuction that takes two arguments, each `Handle`.  When it's applied to two handles, as in the expression `loop inHandle outHandle`, the resulting value is of type `IO ()`.  That means it's an IO action, specifically, the IO action created by the outer do-block in the definition of `loop`.  This do-block creates an IO action that -- when it is executed -- executes two IO actions in order, as given by the lines of the outer do-block.  The first line is:

```
end <- hIsEOF inHandle
```

which takes the IO action `hEof inHandle` (a value of type `IO Bool`), executes it (which consists of asking the operating system if we've reached the end of file for the file represented by handle `inHandle`), and names the result `end` -- note that `end` will be a value of type `Bool`.

The second line of the do-block is the entire `if` statement.  It produces a value of type `IO ()`, so a second IO action.  The IO action depends on the value of `end`.  If `end` is true, the IO action will be the value of `return ()` which, if executed, will perform no actual I/O and will produce a value `()` of type `()`.  If `end` is false, the IO action will be the value of the inner do-block.  This inner do-block is an IO action (a value of type `IO ()`) which, if executed, will execute three IO actions in order:

1. The IO action `hGetLine inHandle`, a value of type `IO String` that, when executed, will read a line from `inHandle` and produce the resulting `String`.  As per the do-block, this result will be given the name `line`.
2. The IO action `hPutStrLn outHandle line`, a value of type `IO ()` that, when exectued, will write `line` to `outHandle`.
3. The IO action `loop inHandle outHandle`, a recursive use of the IO action produced by the outer do-block, which -- when executed -- starts the whole process over again, starting with the EOF check.

If you put these two definitions (for `myAction` and `loop`) in a program, they won't do anything, because they're just definitions of IO actions.  The only way to have them execute is to name one of them `main`, like so:

```
main :: IO ()
main = myAction
```

Of course, we could have just used the name `main` in place of `myAction` to get the same effect, as in the whole program:

```
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
  inHandle <- openFile "in.txt" ReadMode
  outHandle <- openFile "out.txt" WriteMode
  loop inHandle outHandle
  hClose inHandle
  hClose outHandle

loop :: Handle -> Handle -> IO ()
loop inHandle outHandle = do
  end <- hIsEOF inHandle
  if end
    then return ()
    else do
      line <- hGetLine inHandle
      hPutStrLn outHandle line
      loop inHandle outHandle
```

Take some time to compare this to your "concrete example" above, and see where it's different and where it's simliar.  In particular, can you figure out why I wrote:

```
end <- hIsEOF inHandle
if end
  then ...
```

instead of:

```
if hIsEOF inHandle
  then ...
```

#### Copying lines with a line count

To modify this program to count lines, a fairly standard way to do it would be to make the count a parameter to the `loop` function, and have `loop` produce the final value of the count.  Since the expression `loop inHandle outHandle` is an IO action (above, it's of type `IO ()`), to have it produce a count we need to give it type `IO Int`, as you've done in your example.  It will still be an IO action but now -- when it is executed -- it'll produce a useful `Int` value instead of a useless `()` value.

To make this change, `main` will have to invoke loop with a starting counter, name the value it produces, and output that value to the user.

To make it absolutely clear:  `main`'s value is still an IO action created by a do-block.  We're just modifying one of the lines of the do-block.  It used to be:

```
loop inHandle outHandle
```

which evaluated to a value of type `IO ()` representing an IO action that -- when the whole do-block was executed -- would be executed when its turn came to copy the lines from one file to the other before producing a `()` value to be thrown away.  Now, it's going to be:

```
count <- loop inHandle outHandle 0
```

where the right-hand side will evaluate to a value of type `IO Int` representing an IO action that -- when the whole do-block is executed -- will be executed when its turn comes to copy the lines from one file to the other before producing a count value of type `Int` to be named `count` for later do-block steps.

Anyway, the modified `main` looks like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  inHandle <- openFile "in.txt" ReadMode
  outHandle <- openFile "out.txt" WriteMode
  count <- loop inHandle outHandle 0
  hClose inHandle
  hClose outHandle
  putStrLn (show count)    -- could just write @print count@
```

Now, we rewrite `loop` to maintain a count (taking the running count as a parameter through recursive calls and producing the final value when the IO action is executed):

```
loop :: Handle -> Handle -> Int -> IO Int
loop inHandle outHandle count = do
  end <- hIsEOF inHandle
  if end
    then return count
    else do
      line <- hGetLine inHandle
      hPutStrLn outHandle line
      loop inHandle outHandle (count + 1)
```

The whole program is:

```
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
  inHandle <- openFile "in.txt" ReadMode
  outHandle <- openFile "out.txt" WriteMode
  count <- loop inHandle outHandle 0
  hClose inHandle
  hClose outHandle
  putStrLn (show count)    -- could just write @print count@

loop :: Handle -> Handle -> Int -> IO Int
loop inHandle outHandle count = do
  end <- hIsEOF inHandle
  if end
    then return count
    else do
      line <- hGetLine inHandle
      hPutStrLn outHandle line
      loop inHandle outHandle (count + 1)
```

#### The rest of your question

Now, you asked about how to use an accumulator within a do-block without using another function.  I don't know if you meant without using another function besides `loop` (in which case the answer above satisfies the requirement) or if you meant without using any explicit `loop` at all.

If the latter, there are a couple of approaches.  First, there are monadic loop combinators available in the `monad-loops` package that can allow you to do the following (to copy without counting).  I've also switched to using `withFile` in place of explicit open/close calls:

```
import Control.Monad.Loops
import System.IO
main :: IO ()
main =
  withFile "in.txt" ReadMode $ \inHandle ->
  withFile "out.txt" WriteMode $ \outHandle ->
    whileM_ (not <$> hIsEOF inHandle) $ do
      line <- hGetLine inHandle
      hPutStrLn outHandle line
```

and you can count lines with a state monad:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Loops
import System.IO
main :: IO ()
main = do
  n <- withFile "in.txt" ReadMode $ \inHandle ->
       withFile "out.txt" WriteMode $ \outHandle ->
       flip execStateT 0 $
         whileM_ (not <$> liftIO (hIsEOF inHandle)) $ do
           line <- liftIO (hGetLine inHandle)
           liftIO (hPutStrLn outHandle line)
           modify succ
  print n
```

With respect to removing the last `do` block from the definition of `loop` above, there's no good reason to do this.  It's not like `do` blocks have overhead or introduce some extra processing pipeline or something.  They're just ways of constructing IO action values.  So, you *could* replace:

```
else do
  line <- hGetLine inHandle
  hPutStrLn outHandle line
  loop inHandle outHandle (count + 1)
```

with

```
else hGetLine inHandle >>= hPutStrLn outHandle >> loop inHandle outHandle (count + 1)
```

but this is a purely syntactic change.  The two are otherwise identical (and will almost certainly compile to equivalent code).

Comment: `IORef` would be easier for a beginner to handle than `StateT` imo, but otherwise this is an excellent answer

Comment: I find the "is an IO action" language extremely confusing, even with the immediate qualifier about it being a "recipe".  I think just saying "is an IO action recipe" right away is much much clearer. Could not agree more about starting with the do notation. (just thought of something -- what about using "Doable" for Monads, as the parallel of "Mappable" for Functors...? as hints for the newbies of course, not as a serious naming proposal.)

Comment: contd. so, it would read as "(1) In Haskell, any value of type `IO a` is an I/O actions recipe. This recipe describes some I/O actions that can be executed to perform some actual input/output resulting in producing some value of type `a`. So, a value of type `IO String` is an I/O actions recipe that, if executed, will perform those input/output actions and produce a value of type `String` as a result. ... (3) Several I/O actions recipes can be combined using do-notation into a single combined I/O actions recipe" .... For your consideration. :) (haven't yet read the rest...)

Comment: (cf. a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323300/using-return-vs-not-using-return-in-the-list-monad/11326549#11326549) by Conor McBride, with a picture).

Comment: but, having read through more of your excellent answer, I see that this change would necessitate a pretty extensive re-write, so, never mind. :) (to clarify: "action" is confusing to me because, for me, "action" is something that is already being executed, is already being performed).